# OneDrive settings issue for mobiles-O365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business

Microsoft released new OneDrive admin center and there one option under "Device access" which is set to off by default, but we are not clear whether we can enable it or not.

> Control access from apps that don't use modern authentication

Can we enable above feature? will there be nay effect on old devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some third-party apps and versions of Office prior to Office 2013
>   don't use modern authentication and can't enforce device-based
>   restrictions. This means they allow users to bypass conditional access
>   policies that you configure in Azure.

So if you want to block access from apps that don't use modern authentication then you should set it to on. Else leave it as it as.

Reference - [Control access based on network location or app](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Control-access-based-on-network-location-or-app-59b83701-cefd-4bf8-b4d1-d4659b60da08)

If you want to enable/disable it, you need Global admin or atleast Onedrive admin permission.

After that, you can go to Onedrive admin center at below url:

```
https://admin.onedrive.com/?v=AccessPolicySettings
```

Here you can turn the setting on/off as per your policy. After that click on Save and wait for some time for the changes to get propagated.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I want to know more on this, if this is enabled will it block devices which doesn't use modern authentication. if yes then what kind of devices will effect?

Comment: Check this link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access-supported-apps. Here, its give you a list of apps which support modern authentication. So any apps which are not listed here will be blocked if this is enabled.